# Why I can't use + operator with Integer and Double in generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I encountered with a strange issue. I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
public static <Type1 extends  Integer, Type2 extends Double > 
               Object addition(Type1 first, Type2 second)
     {
         return second * first;
     }
```

The compiler claims `Operator * cannot be applied to Type2,Type1`. But that types extends Integer and Double which has + operator defined for them. So i really don't understand this

Comment: What's the point of making this method generic in the first place? Nothing extends Double, and nothing extends Integer. They're both final classes.

Comment: Just curious, is your question about + or \*? You seem to be using both interchangeably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are wrong. Neither Integer nor Double or any other objects extending Number class have "+" or any other operator definied. 
The only reason why you are able to perform something like (Integer + Double) is autoboxing. And autoboxing is a kind of "hardcoded" feature which applies to a very small predefined set of classes, such as Integer, Double, etc.

Furthermore, Integer and all other Number subclasses are declared "final", therefore "Type extends Integer" has no meaning, since you cannot extend anything from Integer.

Comment: As per [JLS §5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `double` which can store every possible `int` values.

```
public static double addition(double first, double second)
 {
     return second + first;
 }
```

I assume you wanted `+` for addition, not `*` for multiplication

you can run

```
 double d1 = addition(1, 5.5);
 double d2 = addition(10.1, 5);
 double d3 = addition(1, 2);
 double d4 = addition(10.1, 12.3455);
```

There is no point extending a final class. Your types are basically the types you gave.

Comment: This is not the way to og since you will have to deal with floating numbers precision problems. And at some point you will simplly end up with situation when you 2.0 + 1.0 != 2.0 + 1.0 which is not acceptable when you work with integer values.

Comment: @VladimirOzerov How can storing or calculations on a 32-bit integer value in a 53-bit precision double result in precision errors?  Can you give me an example of when 2.0 + 1.0 is ever not 3.0? Even if this were true, how would this be different if Java supported operators on Wrappers?